# How I can use java code for creating design on android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-framelayout

I am trying to put TextView into FrameLayout into Linear layout.
When I do it using XML it's OK, but using Java code there are problems.
So I can't move text view using layout_gravity in Java code. Also, I don't understand why text matching parent when I use a parameter wrap content. [must be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyaeO.png)

XML code

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/chatBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:layout_gravity="right"/>
        </FrameLayout>
```

Java code

```
FrameLayout fl = new FrameLayout(this);
fl.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText(message);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new 
LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
p.gravity = Gravity.LEFT; tv.setLayoutParams(p);
fl.addView(tv);
LinearLayout chatbox = (LinearLayout)  findViewById(R.id.chatBox);
chatbox.addView(fl, 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are adding `TextView tv` to `FrameLayout`, so you should use `FrameLayout.LayoutParams` for this `TextView`

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams p = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
p.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
tv.setLayoutParams(p);
fl.addView(tv);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to LayoutParams for your Textview not Linearlayout Params. That is causing the problem. You can create it like;

```
tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT))
```

Comment: p is adressing LinearLayout Params which will not work with TextView it needs to be LayoutParams  not LinearLayout Params

Comment: exacly, but you suggested that he didn't set params at all (before edit). he need to use `FrameLayout.LayoutParams` to be exact